# How has Mapbox loaded this image before the map is loaded?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

At Mapbox's site, https://www.mapbox.com/maps/ they appear to load an image until the map is ready to display in the hero banner. How have they done this? Also the map movement on mouse hover is great, how are they doing this as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the map's `load` event [1] to know when the map is finished loading:

```js
map.on('load', function () {

});
```

You can request a static map via the API https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#static.

You can use some HTML, JavaScript and CSS to show the  from the Mapbox Static API while the GL JS map is loading in the background behind your img. Once you have that `load` event you can hide your img to reveal the interactive map.

You must request that PNG image via the Static Map API, as it's against the Mapbox Terms of Service to download and cache it yourself [2].

To ease the map, you just need to listen to mousemove events and then slightly tweak the map bearing and/or pitch with map.jumpTo or map.easeTo [3].

[1] https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map.event:load

[2] https://www.mapbox.com/tos/#[YmtcYmns]

[3] https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#jumpto